# Find the limit of $\frac{x+y+\sin xy}{x^2+y^2+\sin^2 (xy)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, limits, inequality

Find the limit of:
 $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(+\infty, +\infty)}\frac{x+y+\sin xy}{x^2+y^2+\sin^2 (xy)}$$
I think the solution could be:
$$\frac{x+y+\sin xy}{x^2+y^2+\sin^2 (xy)} \le \frac{x+y+\sin xy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{\sin (xy)}{x^2+y^2}$$
Thus obviously the limit is zero. But wolfram alpha says that the limit does not exist. Therefore what is the correct answer?

Comment: Your inequality doesn't prove the limit exist and is $0$

Comment: If so, how to find this limit correctly?

Comment: @mkropkowski What if you differentiate with respect to x both the numerator and denominator and apply the limits.

Comment: Or just divide denominator and numerator by $x^2 + y^2$. Anyway, the limit is $0$.

Comment: @EugenCovaci but this will give me exactly the same expression as before

Comment: could you write this down in a bit more formal manner?

Comment: I'll write an answer

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner gave you the answer. Aside from $1$, all others have limit $0$.

Comment: Still have no idea how to obtain limit from that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: rewrite your exprssion in the form $$\frac{\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2}}{1+\frac{\sin(xy)^2}{x^2+y^2}}$$

Comment: But what next, because i do not know...

Comment: the numerator has the limit zero and the denominator has the limit one for ${x->\infty,y->\infty}$ thus the searched limit is zero

Comment: There is a small mistake here, it is $sin^2(xy)$ not $sin(xy)^2$

Comment: i have wrote $\sin(xy)^2$ what means $\sin^2(xy)$ not $\sin(xy^2)$!!

Answer (score 1):

By the squeeze theorem, your inequality does show that the limit exists and is zero, when used along with the fact that $0 \le \frac{x+y+\sin xy}{x^2+y^2+\sin^2 (xy)}$ when $x \ge 1, y \ge 1$.